# How to query specific column in a UWP application?

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I need to create a login that displays user data after login in a gridview / datatable

I'm able to display the username / password but not the user ID that's needed.
I've also tried creating a class where the values gets stored after login

```
        private bool DataValidation(string user, string pass)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * "+
                "FROM member " +
                "WHERE username=@user AND password=@pass;", conn))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);



                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<Connect> connectList = new List<Connect>();

                while (login.Read())
                {
                    Connect connect = new Connect();
                    connect.username = login.GetString(0);
                    connect.password = login.GetString(1);
                    connect.userID = login.GetString(4);
                    connectList.Add(connect);

                }

                if(connectList.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I'm mostly not sure how to store or display the values after they have been queried

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've given us a LOT of code to wade through here. It would be extremely helpful if you could narrow down the code you are showing us to exactly the area you are having trouble. In your last line, you said, `I'm mostly not sure how to store or display the values after they have been queried`... So let's start here:  What values?  And can you show us the exact code where they are being queried?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston "using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * "+
                "FROM member " +
                "WHERE username=@user AND password=@pass;", conn))"
And I want to use this result to display the id column value

Comment: Ok.  You are running a SELECT statement here. So, if I am understanding you correctly, you are wondering how to get the result of that query and assign each column to a variable in C#? Is that correct?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Yes that is correct, I then want to assign those values to my class and use them just by calling the class var

Comment: Which class is that?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston The name is Connect :INotifyPropertyChanged and it just stores the get; set ;values
With this function  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

Comment: I edited your post to cut WAY down on the amount of code shown.  No need to overwhelm your post with more code than what is needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, let's focus on this code:

```
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (login.Read())
{
    conn.Close();
    return true;
}
else
{
    conn.Close();
    return false;
}
```

The only thing we are doing here is finding out if `login` contains any rows. But we are not doing anything *with* those rows.

Let's try something like this instead:

```
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (login.Read())
{
    var something1 = login.GetString(0); // this will get the value of the first column
    var something2 = login.GetString(1); // this will get the value of the second column
}
```

Or, if you are adding the results to an object:

```
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
List<MyObject> myObjectList  = new List<MyObject>;
while (login.Read())
{
    MyObject myObject  = new MyObject;
    myObject.something1 = login.GetString(0); // this will get the value of the first column
    myObject.something2 = login.GetString(1); // this will get the value of the first column
    myObjectList.Add(myObject);
}

if (myObjectList.Count > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

You will need to adjust to meet your needs, but hopefully, this will get you there.

More info here: [SqlDataReader.Read Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I've tried using creating the list object but for some reason the value returns a NULL on all objects?